# Trouble converting SQL Lite Query to Model Query with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sqlite, entity-framework-core, razor-pages

I have a database table that has a series of notifications.  There can be multiple notifications for the same city, xgrid and ygrid. So I am getting the latest date and using that record via the SQL Lite query.

After reading through several articles on this site I have tried to piece together the Model Query equivalent to the SQL Lite query below.

The Problem is the Model Query has no compilation errors, but the results are null.

**SQL Lite Query**

```
select * from (
    select
        NOTIFY_ID,
        NOTIFICATION_DATE,
        CITY_NAME,
        ITEM_X_GRID,
        ITEM_Y_GRID,
        GRID_QUANTITY,
        row_number() over(partition by ITEM_X_GRID, ITEM_Y_GRID, CITY_NAME order by NOTIFICATION_DATE desc) as rn
    from
        USER_ILLY_DATA
) t
where t.rn = 1
order by CITY_NAME
```

**Class & List**

```
        public class MostRecentNotify
        {
            public int RecordID { get; set; }
            public string ItemXGrid { get; set; }
            public string ItemYGrid { get; set; }
            public string GridQuantity { get; set; }
            public string NotificationDate { get; set; }
            public string CityName { get; set; }
            public string IllyItemCode { get; set; }
        }

        public IList<MostRecentNotify> RecentNotifies { get; set; }
```

**Model Query To Get Latest Record (not working)**

```
var tempResults = _context.IllyAPIData.GroupBy(i => new { i.ItemXGrid, i.ItemYGrid, i.CityName})
                .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(y => y.NotificationDate).FirstOrDefault());
```

**Model Query to Pass values to Class to be called in Razor Pages**

```
            var RecentNotifies = tempResults.Select(r => new MostRecentNotify//).ToListAsync();
                                        {
                                            ItemXGrid = r.ItemXGrid,
                                            ItemYGrid = r.ItemYGrid,
                                            GridQuantity = r.GridQuantity,
                                            NotificationDate = r.NotificationDate,
                                            CityName = r.CityName,
                                            IllyItemCode = r.IllyriadCode,
                                            RecordID = r.RecordID,
                                        }).ToListAsync();
```

**Razor Pages snippet**

```
@foreach (var item in Model.RecentNotifies.Where(i => i.CityName == city.DistinctCityName)){
    @foreach (var indRes in Model.RareResources.Where(r => r.ResourceCode == item.IllyItemCode)){
```

**Error on Page Load**

```
ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')
System.Linq.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument argument)
System.Linq.Enumerable.Where<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
IllyriadAssist.Pages.harvestableInventory.Pages_harvestableInventory_Index.ExecuteAsync() in Index.cshtml
+ @foreach (var item in Model.RecentNotifies.Where(i => i.CityName == city.DistinctCityName)){
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context, bool invokeViewStarts)
```

Comment: What is `Model.RecentNotifies`? You doesn't seem to assign the result to it (`var RecentNotifies = …` just assigns the query result to temporary variable), hence it will be `null`. `ToList()` / `ToListAsync()` never produce `null`.

Comment: @ivanStoev perhaps I am looking at it wrong but I thought since I was calling `tempResults` into `RecentNotifies` I would be selecting all the results from that query into `RecentNotifies` and assigning them into the class with the properties / results I want.   `Model.RecentNotifies` is calling the specific Model cs (`harvestableInventory.cs`) -
`@model IAssistApp.Pages.harvestableInventory.IndexModel`- which is where the DB Context and associated classes/methods reside.  That is why I believe the first query `tempResults` is not returning results. breakpoint shows `RecentNotifies` null

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more poking around I was able to get the queries to work by doing it this way:

```
            var tempData = from c in _context.IllyAPIData
                           group c by new { c.CityName, c.ItemXGrid, c.ItemYGrid } into g
                           select new
                           {
                               g.Key.CityName,
                               g.Key.ItemXGrid,
                               g.Key.ItemYGrid,
                               NotifyDate = g.Max(a => a.NotificationDate)
                           };
            var RecentNotifies = (from c in _context.IllyAPIData
                                  join s in tempData
                                     on new { c.CityName, c.ItemXGrid, c.ItemYGrid }
                                         equals new { s.CityName, s.ItemXGrid, s.ItemYGrid }
                                  where c.NotificationDate == s.NotifyDate
                                  select c).ToListAsync();
```